# How do I pass value of a variable in jquery to PHP without submitting form or refreshing the page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

My ajax is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    datatype: 'html',
    data: { password : password}
});
```

Have been trying to store it in `$pword`. But it doesn't store.
PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['password']))
{
    // store session data
    $pword=$_POST['password'];
}
```

HTML is this:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: How did you understand  that `it doesn't store`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @u_mulder, I echo'ed it.

Comment: @IvanBarayev that one looks too complicated for me. I am new to PHP.

Comment: dont set the datatype, jquery can figure it out and you're sending a json object, not html

Answer (score 2):

first of all : **there is nothing wrong with server side (PHP) and HTML code.**

so for jQuery portion : you need to correct a line like i did below:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: { 
              password : $("#password").val()
              //here i asked jquery to fetch entire value of my html input(with an id of "password") as text(Not an Object) so it gives me the entered text value.
                  }})
                .success(function(data) {                        alert(data.toString());
        });//optional function:runs when server responses to your request
```

i can leave more detailed help if you explain what exactly you r going to do.

Comment: I am simply transferring password entered by user to check from the database if any entry matches there.

Comment: to transform any thing via ajax you need a server(to run PHP code) and a client(which gets and sends users password ) . how you implemented server part?

Comment: i checked out my snippet and it works. if you put whole file here it'll be easier to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#password').on('blur',function(){
    var password = $('#password').val();

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: { password : password
           },
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }

        });


})
})
</script>

<form method="post">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript **setTimeout** function to pass the form value into php page as mentioned below,

I have added a function called **passData()** inside the **setTimeout** function, so it calls the **passData()** function mentioned delay.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
setTimeout(function() { passData() }, 3000);

function passData(){
   var password = $("#password").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'index.php',
        datatype: 'html',
        data: { password : password}
    }); 
}
```

Comment: why not a simple button to send the data?

Comment: @Vineet Basantani, can you please check your error console, do you get any errors, check jquery library added into your page.

Comment: What does the use of `setTimeout` accomplish here? The actual passing of data in your example is accomplished using a function that you don't even mention in your answer.

Comment: @duskwuff because OP is expected like "without submitting form or refreshing the page?"

Comment: @Vineet Basantani, I have updated my answer, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

use form.serialize() to send data.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: form.serialize()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From jquery documentation the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Another suggestion would be to create a button. When pressing it the data will be sent to the PHP file.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

The jQuery code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "my-php-file.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { password: $('#password').val() }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data sent: " + msg );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by `store session data`. If you want to store it in a session variable to be used later in other php files then you should `start_session()` at the top of the file and store the password in the session variable: `$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']`. Be aware that doing it like this, without encrypting the password, is very dangerous, so take the encryption in consideration.

Comment: I have started the session. Don't worry about the security, I don't have launch codes in there. I just want it to work.

Comment: But even `$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']` is not getting the value

Comment: Try it with the additional parameter `dataType: 'json'`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
<input type="button" onclick="sendData()" value="Ok">
```

**Javascript**

```js
function sendData(){
   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'index.php',
        datatype: 'html',
        data: { password : $("#password").val()}
    }); 
}
```